# Resolving conflicts with branch containing features we don't want to move forward

Tags: git

Apologies in advance if this question doesn't make much sense.

We have three branches `Dev`, `Master` and `Stable`. When we create a new feature, we create that from Stable and then create pull requests to `Dev` and `Master`.

It will first get deployed on `Dev`, then on `Master` and eventually merged back to `Stable` when it goes to production.

My feature branch `S1` is created from `Stable` and I am trying to create a pull request to `Dev` but some files are ending up in conflict with `Dev` and I need to resolve this conflict.

This is the current situation

```
Dev
  -- D1
  -- D2

Master 
  -- M1

Stable
  -- S1
```

The change made in `S1` conflicts with changes made in `D1`. To resolve the conflict I can simply merge the `Dev` branch into my feature branch.

But if I do that then when I move `S1` to `Master` **it will also carry D2 with it**. I don't want that. `D2` needs to stay in `Dev` for a longer period of time and I only need to move `D1` forward to `Master` and `Stable`.

I can also create two separate feature branches one from `Dev` and one from `Master` and then merge them back to `Dev` and `Master` respectively and create a release branch from `Master`. But this will create too many branches.

How can I resolve conflict in situation like this?

Answer (score 2):

If D1 and D2 are sequentials (first D1 commits, then D2), you can also:

- create a tmp branch at D1
- rebase S1 top of D1 (resolving conflicts locally)
- merge S1 to Dev (where you test D1 and D2)